# Detect variable change in python

Tags: python

I am trying to detect a variable change in this youtube subscriber count detector. There is probably a easy answer to this, but I just want to detect if a there is a new subscriber. Here is the code.

```
import urllib.request

import json
import lightsOff




name="UCFCXay6rKDhsL41Zq-q9P-A"

key = "Api_Key"


while True:

  data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+name+"&key="+key).read()
  subs=json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]

  print(subs)
```

Comment: You can set a variable like `last_count` and ask in every iteration if `subs!=last_count`. You should use too something like time.sleep(5) in every iteration, so you will not ask for the subs needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably store the subscriber count from the last loop in a variable, and get the new one. Something like

```py
data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+name+"&key="+key).read()
subs=json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
while True:
  data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+name+"&key="+key).read()
  newSubCount=json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
  if newSubCount>subs:
    print('new sub')
  subs=newSubCount
```